# Loop through a list and insert html elements depending on Odd or Even in Angular

Tags: html, angular, bulma

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to understand how to loop through a list

Lets say I have a list like the one in the Tour of Heroes Tutorial.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

```
    export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' }      
];
```

I use Bulma for styling and would like to insert the Heroes list in a Columns with two column pr row.
https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/

The end result looking something like this.

```
     <div class="container">
          <div class="columns">
             <div class="column">
                11 Mr. Nice
             </div>
            <div class="column">
                12 Narco
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="columns">
             <div class="column">
                13 Bombasto
             </div>
            <div class="column">
                14 Celeritas
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="columns">
             <div class="column">
                15 Magneta
             </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

There is some documentation about values like first, last, even & odd
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

But I can't figure out how to use them. Because if the element i *Odd* Then I would have to  add the start element  `<div class="columns">` and if its *Even* i would have to add the closing element  and of course the special case where the list contains and odd numbers of elements, then I would have to add an empty `<div class="column"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be made with `first, last, even & odd` too, but the optimal way is to be able to implement your html tags so you can use the *ngFor whitout `first, last, even & odd`.

solution:
Due to the file structure mentioned above, I suggest you chunk the array at component.

try:

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
 { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
 { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
 { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
 { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
 { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' }      
];
HEROES = chunkArray(HEROES, 2);

function chunkArray(array, chunkSize) {
    return Array(Math.ceil(array.length / chunk_size)).fill().map((_, index) 
           => index * chunk_size).map(begin => array.slice(begin, begin + 
           chunk_size))
}
```

now HEROES is:

```
[
 [{"id":11,"name":"Mr. Nice"},{"id":12,"name":"Narco"}], 
 [{"id":13,"name":"Bombasto"},{"id":14,"name":"Celeritas"}], 
 [{"id":15,"name":"Magneta"}]
]
```

try in html:

[image]